# How to Reload a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I have two classes `CreateAppointment` and `DailyView`. `DailyView` calls `CreateAppointment` using an `ActionListener`. The purpose of `CreateAppointment` is to create an appointment and then cancel or confirm if the user is ready to add it to the JFrame in `DailyView`. The thing I'm confused about is when I create an appointment and I click the `confirm` button, I want the `ActionListener` to reload the JFrame with the new appointment in `DailyView` window and close the `CreateAppointment` window.

I know I use `dispose()` to close the `CreateAppointment` window, but I'm not sure if its possible to reload the `DailyView` window within another class.

Comment: `CreateAppointment` should probably be a `JDialog`, this way, the execution will stop at the point the dialog is made visible and continue when it's disposed/closed, allowing you to extract the details from the dialog, update any models and further trigger updates to the UI

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
```

If it still doesn't work then after completing the above step try

```
frame.invalidate();
frame.validate();
frame.repaint();
```